# Login Form in first page MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

I whant to put login form on the beginig of site (like gmail). So when user visit to site, first what he/she see is login form.

In HomeController I put this codes:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(); // (view) ~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult LogedIn()
    {
        return View(); // (view) ~/Views/Home/LogedIn.cshtml
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(Models.Users uporabnik)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (IsValid(uporabnik.Username, uporabnik.Password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(uporabnik.Username, false);
                return RedirectToAction("LogedIn", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Error!");
            }
        }
        return View(uporabnik); // (view) ~/Views/Home/LogedIn.cshtml
    }

    public ActionResult LogOut()
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    private bool IsValid(string userSol, string passSol)
    {
      ...
    }
```

Map Views / Home have this codes:

Index.cshtml

```
@model MyModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Solr-Actual</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="../Content/Site.css" />
</head>

<body>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Home"))
{
  <div class="prijavno-okno">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Login form:</legend>
        <form method="get">
            <label>Username:</label>@Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Username)<br/> 
            <label>Password:</label>@Html.PasswordFor(u => u.Password)<br/>
            <input class="gumb" type="submit" value="Login">
        </form>
    </fieldset>
</div>  
}

</body>

</html>
```

LogedIn.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "LogedIn";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>LogedIn</h2>
```

Login.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
}

<h2>Error</h2>

@Html.ActionLink("Back", "Index", "Home")
```

**Problem is, when I click Login button (after enter username and password, I have enter my user on databese manualy) page stays in first Login page... What is wrong?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create the `form` tag by using [`Html.BeginForm`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform%28v=vs.118%29.aspx). You can put the action name in the code then:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "Controller"))
{
    ... // your exising code
}
```

You should rewrite your inner form code too, so it use [`Html.TextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textbox%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) and [`Html.Password`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460493%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) for example.

Comment: I get Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found.

Comment: @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home"))
{
      <div class="prijavno-okno">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Login form:</legend>
            <form method="get">
                <label>Username:</label>@Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Username)<br/> 
                <label>Password:</label>@Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Password)<br/>
                <input class="gumb" type="submit" value="Login">
            </form>
        </fieldset>
    </div>  
}

Comment: Isn't your action name 'Login'?

Comment: Am, remove? how do you mean?

Comment: Oww, my bed I even didn't see that, I was fast clicking, and by accident I click it. I apologise for that. Thanks for notice me, once againg I realy apologise for that.

Comment: @user3493876: No problem. Just upvote useful answers. That will be a good incentive for users providing an answer. I just upvoted sanjay's answer. You could do the same.

Answer (score 1):

You Have to set FormMethod in Html.BeginForm like

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login","Home",FormMethod.Post))// Add Post Method to Your Code
{
  //Your code.
}
```

It should work.